# How to create transparent semicircle?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, drawable

I want to create this effect.TextView with transparent semicircle as backgound .  [image]
I tried add drawable as background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

also i tried this [stackoverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962745/draw-a-semicircle-in-the-background-of-a-view) ,but it doesn't work for me.
Can anyone help me?