# How to create a semi - rounded imageview in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a Semi-circle/rounded imageview. Below is the code which i use to create a rounded imageview but i am unable to create a semi-rounded image (semi-circle)

```
package com.example.dynamicviews;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Customized Imageview with Rounded Border and Shadow
 * @author Rahul Gupta <rahulg@exzeo.com>
 * @since 2014-01-01
 */
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView
{
    private int borderWidth = 2;
    private int viewWidth;
    private int viewHeight;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBorder;
    private BitmapShader shader;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();
    }

    /**
     * Custom Class to round imageview with color
     * @param context Context of the activity
     * @param borderColor Border color to be set
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public RoundedImageView(Context context, String borderColor) {
        super(context);
         // init paint
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintBorder = new Paint();
        setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(3.0f, 0.0f,1.0f, Color.parseColor(borderColor));
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setup()
    {
        // init paint
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintBorder = new Paint();
        setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(3.0f, 0.0f,1.0f, Color.BLACK);
        loadBitmap();
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)
    {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)
    {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void loadBitmap()
    {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

        if (bitmapDrawable != null)
            image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // load the bitmap

        // init shader
        if (image != null)
        {
            shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;

            // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
            // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
            // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter - 4.0f, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
        viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Measure the text
            result = viewWidth;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
            result = viewHeight;
        }

        return (result + 2);
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot for it :-
[image]

**The desired result is shown below :- Two imageview's left semi circle and right semi circle with image resource in between :-**

[image]

Comment: Can you also post an image showing the desired result?

Comment: See [this](http://blog.mwrobel.eu/howt-draw-semicircle-android-canvasenhow-draw-semicircle-android-canvas/). or you can use **drawArc** instead of **drawCircle**: see [this](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2009/01/02/Android-Draw-a-Curved-Line)

Comment: @AtulOHolic - added the desired result image

Comment: @ArtooDetoo - i have tried that link. it does not work in my case

Comment: Maybe the second link will help you more... drawArc (combined with a drawLine).

Comment: @ArtooDetoo - can you please post an answer using draw arc. i am unable to do it

Comment: Found a perfect example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15963620/2649012). I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: It is good but i set it as image view's background and then set an image resource. It is not coming into centre. I want the image view's bound to be semicircle. Circular was easy. Semi circle is really irritating

Comment: I will put a bounty of 100 after two days as this question is very important to me. I have to find a good solution.

Comment: http://blog.mwrobel.eu/howt-draw-semicircle-android-canvasenhow-draw-semicircle-android-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

One of my project I have same half circle and inside Need to show some image,
So I just use simple trick,I just create one half circle image and set as src of image view and then I set another image as background.
you can also have some trick like just create simple frame layout and set some half circle image as a background and use some image view in side that frame layout and set some other image to that image view.
I hope this might give you some basic idea for achieving your task.
good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did in a javascript project was to put div with rounded corners with radius equal to half of width/height. For semi-circle, you could do a rectangle of h x w, where h=2*w. Top-left and bottom-left radius r would be r=w.

A link to an answer that says how to round corners in Android:
[round corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners)

I know it's not complete, but it gives an idea. And creativity is all about getting different ways to solve unique problems. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="semicircle">
<solid android:background="@drawable/yourimage" />
<size android:width="60dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

then in your class `id = shape` lets say

```
Shape shape = (Shape) findViewById(R.id.shape);
shape.split(10dp , center);
```