# linear layout with text and image view which is cropped

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/curvedimage" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

at present this is my view as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHKOY.png)
 i need the image view displayed in cropped format as shown

[image: here] thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use [CircularImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)  and use RelativeLayout to place Image over TextView

Comment: i need only one side to be circular

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017850/how-to-create-a-semi-rounded-imageview-in-android