# android how to make inner view circle shape as shown in Picture

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout

i want to achieve the following shape with circle background, i have tried but my inner view is not getting in circle shape in Relative layout i will post my screen shot .

[image]

and I am getting the following Result with the layout i cerated
[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whitecircle" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/circle_layoutinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rating_viewtv"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circletwo" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ratingcup_viewtv_fonts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Y"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating_viewtv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:text="4.5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my whitecircle.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

**my circletwo.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#ff9546" />

</shape>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14106539/1576416 this link might help you to move ahead and achieve your requirement.

Comment: hi thanku for your reply , but is it possible with my current logic that i have posted my layout above ?

Comment: you can draw only white circle with layout xml but not orange. so draw your shape on canvas and convert it to bitmap. and use that bitmap wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circletwo" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/circle_layoutinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rating_viewtv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ratingcup_viewtv_fonts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Y"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating_viewtv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4.5"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**try this too using linear layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circletwo"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ratingcup_viewtv_fonts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.2"
        android:text="Y"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating_viewtv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4.5"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have used your code, if you see my requirement the background is blue the with your code i am not getting the output in complete circle, as you can see in first pic with blue background?

Comment: please anyone guide me?

Comment: check out this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962745/draw-a-semicircle-in-the-background-of-a-view

Comment: i think i have to change my current logic according to the link you send to me. is there any way to do this?

Comment: what logic u want to change?

Comment: i mean to create semi circle

Comment: if it is possible with image please tell me how to do this?

Comment: make a circular image with two colors n set it as background for parent layout and with linear layout weight u place ur views n try i hope it works for u..