# Android hide a view partially behind screen

Tags: android, view, imageview

Hello I am working with android.I have a custom imageview.I want to hide partial imageview behind the screen. I tried padding=-100... etc. But its not working .How can I hide a view partially behind screen ?

Comment: Hi could you be a bit more clear about what you want to achieve and if possible provide some reference image for it.

Comment: i have a circle . I am looking to hide partially bahind screen to make it a semi circle

Answer (score 1):

use negative margin to parent layout like this, its working

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"** >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your view through java or make a drawable of semicircle and set it as background of imageview.

Refer this: [Semicircle drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962745/draw-a-semicircle-in-the-background-of-a-view)