# How to add elevation to transparent ImageView [android]

Tags: android, android-elevation

Is it really to implement elevation of ImageView with png that contains transparent background? For example: i want to add elevation shadow to this pic:

[image]

Want make it like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @AyushSth Just added it as a png with a shadow as shown above... That was 2015.. Maybe now it can be solved correct way but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML add this:

```
android:elevation="2dp"    
android:background="@drawable/myrect"
```

In your Drawable folder add this drawable:

```
<!-- res/drawable/myrect.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

See here for more info: http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Comment: i know that. but it will add only rectangle shadow around the View. I want to add shadow only around NON transparent pixels in my ImageView.

Comment: Change the radius to match your object's radius

Comment: it makes only rectangle or full circle shadows.

Comment: how can i draw this shape in drawable?

Comment: See this answer for half circle drawables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962745/draw-a-semicircle-in-the-background-of-a-view