# Is there any way how to create half circle as shape?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I want to create special view for my app. It is vertical dotted line and two half circles on a top and bottom. Is there any way how to create this as single shape drawable? I made dotted line, but I cant make half circle.

It should looks like this.

[image]

Dotted vertical line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fromDegrees="90" android:toDegrees="90">
    <shape
            android:shape="line">
        <stroke
                android:color="#777777"
                android:dashWidth="7dp"
                android:dashGap="5dp"
                android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

I have found as someone tried to make half circle, but its big. I need only small circle. And it is not even circle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="100000dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="100000dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <solid android:color="#777777" />
</shape>
```

Comment: You can specify size property in the shape as well to make it small.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043351/half-circle-shape-not-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `half_circle.xml` file under `drawable` with this line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#8C9AEE"/>
    <size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="60dp"/>
   <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
    android:topRightRadius="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

set `half_circle.xml` as background of layout

output will be look like :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can draw the whole view with the help of [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) in android. And use the [Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) to define how it will be and [Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint) object to define its color.