# AppBar Layout Transparent Background

Tags: java, android

[image]

Codes:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


        <com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:arc_cropDirection="cropOutside"
            app:arc_height="30dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vkiscrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="604dp"
        android:background="@color/darkblue"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent">

                    CONTENT....



        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to delete the background seen in the image (under arc layout gray backgroundcolor)..
The background color of every place did not transparently. 
I want to use arc layout in my project or arc shape ETC. I wrote all the codes above.. Also, How to draw a xml shape like arc layout?

It doesn't try everything. Please help me

Thanks in advance..

Comment: this link may this answer [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043351/half-circle-shape-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the background color you're setting to the arclayout is transparent ? These are the codes for color transparency. Put value in front of color value. Example :

**FF**FF2D00

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:background="#00000000"
```

try this it work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately :(  It is not

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `ArcLayout` outside `AppBarLayout` like below:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:arc_cropDirection="cropOutside"
            app:arc_height="30dp">


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/vkiscrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="604dp"
            android:background="@color/darkblue">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately :( Didn't work again. In arcview stands a gray background outside. How do I make arcview-like shape at 90 dp height?

Comment: In my case, I don't see the gray bar

Comment: Hey, I have set `app:elevation="0dp"` in `AppBarLayout`. Probably you missed that

Comment: Replace your `layout` with my one and check

Comment: Screenshot;  https://ibb.co/bBw59xv    I did everything you said. (Before scrolling and after scrolling) It's not working

Comment: If the is caused by app bar layout, can the problem be in arcview? What else can I write instead of view  @asaduzzaman